# Error SML : Error: unbound variable or constructor: valof

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am taking the Programming Languages course offered by Washington University, during one of the lectures, this code popped up worked for professor Dan, however, I am getting unbound variable or constructor:valof error. Could not figure it out.
it is smlnj, and running on emacs, if it would yield any help.

```
fun max1(xs: int list)=
    if null xs
    then NONE
    else
        let val tl_ans = max1(tl xs)
        in if isSome tl_ans andalso valof tl_ans > hd xs
            then tl_ans
            else SOME (hd xs)
        end
```

here is the error: **options.sml:7.37-7.42 Error: unbound variable or constructor: valof**

Comment: Try `valOf` instead (with a capital O).

Comment: Yup, that worked very finely! thank you. Interesting thing is that professors' code was with lower o. Thanks again!

Comment: A bit of a tangential thought, but it certainly seems like this code could be substantially improved with a bit of pattern matching. `isSome tl_ans andalso valof tl_ans` is definitely a code smell.

Comment: The professor probably didn't run his own code. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quoify says, it's spelled `valOf`.

And as kopecs says, if you use pattern matching, it will be much shorter:

```
fun max1 (x::y::rest) = max1 (Int.max (x, y) :: rest)
  | max1 [x] = SOME x
  | max1 [] = NONE
```

(This version also uses the library function `Int.max` for added brevity.)

If this is too compact, you could also write:

```
fun max1 (x::y::rest) = let val z = Int.max (x, y) in max1 (z::rest) end
  | max1 [x] = SOME x
  | max1 [] = NONE
```

The version from the slides deals with an annoying situation that arises in many recursive functions that return sum types like `'a option`: You may need to perform a call, do some unpacking (i.e. remove `SOME`), and then pack the result back (i.e. add `SOME` again).

But the `max1` problem does not necessitate that situation.

Comment: Well at this point might as well write the whole thing as a fold too :)

Comment: @kopecs: Yes! :) Or switch to a language where this function is [pre-defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) in a way that takes as input any foldable structure of orderable elements. :)

Comment: Or rather, [`maximumMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio/docs/RIO-List.html#v:maximumMaybe) is the better version.